# Unity Android USB camera auto deny permissions

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, permissions, camera, usb

I'm trying to create a native Android plugin to support external USB cameras.
I'm using serenegiant's library found online that's using BroadcastReceiver to find attached USB devices and request permissions.

The following code works well when is built in Android Studio (native App), but it doesn't work when trying to use it in Unity. When a USB camera is attached a pop up is shown asking "Allow app to access null" [1], but in Unity it automatically fails without asking [2]. Camera permissions are grand in the start of the app as already using the built-in cameras.

```
private final BroadcastReceiver mUsbReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(final Context context, final Intent intent) {
            if (destroyed) return;
            final String action = intent.getAction();
            if (ACTION_USB_PERMISSION.equals(action)) {
                // when received the result of requesting USB permission
                synchronized (USBMonitor.this) {
                    final UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                    if (intent.getBooleanExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_PERMISSION_GRANTED, false)) {
                        if (device != null) {
                            // get permission, call onConnect
                            processConnect(device);
                            // [1] Pop up is Shown
                            Log.i(TAG, "Grand camera permissions");
                        }
                        else{
                            Log.i(TAG, "device is null");
                        }
                    } else {
                        Log.i(TAG, "Failed to grand camera permissions");
                        // failed to get permission
                        processCancel(device);
                        // [2] automatically fails
                    }
                }
            } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED.equals(action)) {
                final UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                updatePermission(device, hasPermission(device));
                processAttach(device);
            } else if (UsbManager.ACTION_USB_DEVICE_DETACHED.equals(action)) {
                // when device removed
                final UsbDevice device = intent.getParcelableExtra(UsbManager.EXTRA_DEVICE);
                if (device != null) {
                    UsbControlBlock ctrlBlock = mCtrlBlocks.remove(device);
                    if (ctrlBlock != null) {
                        // cleanup
                        ctrlBlock.close();
                    }
                    mDeviceCounts = 0;
                    processDettach(device);
                }
            }
        }
    };
```

Edit: Attaching manifests

Native Android:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.jiangdg.usbcamera">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

    <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host"/>

    <application
        android:name=".application.MyApplication"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name="com.jiangdg.usbcamera.view.SplashActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <activity android:name=".view.USBCameraActivity"
            android:screenOrientation="portrait">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Unity Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<man
ifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.unity3d.player" xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">
  <application>
    <activity android:name="com.unity3d.player.UnityPlayerActivity" android:theme="@style/UnityThemeSelector" android:screenOrientation="fullSensor" android:launchMode="singleTask" android:configChanges="mcc|mnc|locale|touchscreen|keyboard|keyboardHidden|navigation|orientation|screenLayout|uiMode|screenSize|smallestScreenSize|fontScale|layoutDirection|density" android:hardwareAccelerated="false">
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.UnityActivity" android:value="true" />
      <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" />
      </intent-filter>
      <meta-data android:name="android.hardware.usb.action.USB_DEVICE_ATTACHED" android:resource="@xml/device_filter" />
      <meta-data android:name="android.notch_support" android:value="true" />
    </activity>
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-mode" android:value="0" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.splash-enable" android:value="True" />
    <meta-data android:name="notch.config" android:value="portrait|landscape" />
    <meta-data android:name="unity.build-id" android:value="8a250566-7f01-48ac-a11d-8b013649efde" />
  </application>
  <meta-data android:name="unityplayer.SkipPermissionsDialog" android:value="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECORD_AUDIO" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.host" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.usb.accessory" />
  <uses-feature android:glEsVersion="0x00020000" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.vulkan.version" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CAMERA" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.autofocus" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.camera.front" android:required="false" />
  <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch" android:required="false" />
  <uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.touchscreen.multitouch.distinct" android:required="false" />
</manifest>
```

Comment: could you attach your Manifest please?

Comment: @Lotan I edited the question and attached the manifests